# Confusion: AngularJS $http POST response is returning HTML content of index file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, rest, restful-authentication

I am using AngularJS which uses a Ruby on Rails API for authentication. I am using the $http service in AngularJS to register a user using a POST request to the backend, however, I am confused as the response I am getting is always returned in HTML and it is of the index page, not the actual data from the rails API. I am testing this in my local environment where the AngularJS app is running on localhost:9000, and the Rails API is on localhost:3000. The AngularJS is using a proxy which directs requests to port 3000.

I have tested the response of the Rails API by using curl commands:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user":{"email":"hi@hi.com","password":"12345678"}}' -X POST http://localhost:9000/api/users.json
```

which returns the response from the server as:

```
{"success":true,"info":"Registered","data":{"user":{"id":5,"created_at":"2016-04-24T14:13:24.289Z","updated_at":"2016-04-24T14:13:24.298Z","email":"hi@hi.com","authentication_token":"-49zyhbCiddYdjssQx6i"},"auth_token":"-49zyhbCiddYdjssQx6i"}}
```

Here is the code in the front-end which is in an AngularJS controller:

```
 $scope.register = function() {
            $http({
                url: '/api/users',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    user: $scope.user
                }
            }).then(
                // success
                function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    console.log(response.auth_token);
                    tokenHandler.set( response.auth_token );
                    $location.path('/');
                },
                // error
                function(response) {
                    $scope.user.errors = response;
                });
        };
```

Here is the server response code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
respond_to :json

def create
build_resource(sign_up_params)

if resource.save
  sign_in resource
  render status: 200,
         json: {
             success: true,
             info: "Registered",
             data: {
                 user: resource,
                 auth_token: current_user.authentication_token
             }
         }
else
  # Otherwise fail
  render status: :unprocessable_entity,
         json: {
             success: false,
             info: resource.errors,
             data: {}
         }
end
end
end
```

However, the response when I call the register method is always in HTML and of the index file of my front-end.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: In your `curl` call your URL is `http://localhost:9000/api/users.json`, while in your `$http` call, the URL is `/api/users`

Comment: I tried using http://localhost:9000/api/users.json in the $http call but it responded the same, with HTML of the index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what is going on. But from the look of your post, this is what I understood (my english is not flawless) :

- When called externally (the Angular apps recieves a request), this request is being fowarded to port 3000 ( proxy ). Hence why you have a proper response from the "curl" call.
- When the Angular app makes a request, it is not forwarded. Hence why asking for /api/users gets you the Angular App index (I suppose there is a failsafe route to index or some reason to explain that behavior).

If that makes any sense, could you test it ?

Answer (score 0):

The proxy seemed to direct the localhost:9000 call to the server, but the response kept being HTML contents of the index file of the front-end. I am unsure about what the actual problem was and unsure about this type of stuff. I fixed this by sending the $http POST request to localhost:3000 rather than localhost:9000.

Answer (score 0):

It seems angular is not making a request expecting json. And rails needs that explicit (your curl command is explicitly requesting json format)

In your angular code you can try changing the url from `url: '/api/users'` to `url: '/api/users.json'`. You can also check how to send the content type expected `application/json` from angular.